# Update JIRA status from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, jira, azure-devops

We are hosting our software in a git repository inside Visual Studio Online (VSO) and using Atlassian / Jira in the cloud for our bug tracking.

Now I want check ins to change the status of bugs to "Fix Committed" based on some kind of indicator text like: "Fixed WEBPROJECT-3454".

Zapier lets you have 5 workflows ("zaps") and has integrations with both Jira and VSO, but the only two Jira actions are create a new ticket or find a user.

I also saw TaskTop, but it was unclear what it did and what the price was.

Next I looked for hooks devs could install on their local machines to run a script that would update the tickets. I saw [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/107630/jira-how-to-change-issue-status-via-rest), but it looked like it wasn't a cloud thing -it seemed to run on a local JIRA server. I have a python script that works successfully with our old Mercurial server ... so I know JIRA supports this, but it has a lot of Mercurial dependencies.

How can I automatically update the ticket to Fix Committed on check ins?

Comment: Doesn't JIRA do this automatically if you configure it properly? [See here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/processing-jira-software-issues-with-smart-commit-messages-298979931.html).

Comment: @Kenney: It does for BitBucket or GitHub. Not an option for VisualStudioOnline apparently.

Comment: Ah that's too bad. I figured it might be able to read git repositories directly, regardless of where they are hosted. Perhaps [this](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xiplink.jira.git.jira_git_plugin/server/overview) is useful? It says it supports smart commits.

Comment: @Kenney: Thanks for the tip. The instructions are a little unclear. You download a .jar file to install for Atlassian (but isn't JIRA in the cloud?). If you go to the Add Ons screen in JIRA (per the instructions) none of them have git in the title and you can't upload jar files.

Comment: @micahhoover if you are running JIRA cloud you would need to select "Cloud" from the drop down at the top right

Answer (score 0):

Got this response from Andre at Atlassian:

I believe you can achieve that by using Smart Commits in JIRA, by integrating it with FishEye. We have a few docs showing how to achieve it, please take a moment to check it and see if that's what you want to achieve:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+smart+commits

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracloud/processing-jira-issues-with-commit-messages-740098538.html

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/processing-jira-software-issues-with-smart-commit-messages-298979931.html

https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/enabling-smart-commits-298976933.html

And I did some dig and we do have an add-on to integrate JIRA with Visual Studio, but it's still on Labs, you can see it [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/PLVS/server/overview).